# I'm getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" on my React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, state

I'm new on React. I have a node.js API. I'm trying to create a login page. I make a request to the API and I can get a response. I put the returned answer into the state named "user". I want to print this to an  tag with the map function and check the data. However, I am getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined." I have defined the state with [] and I don't know what else to do.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yard.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {

  state = { user: [] }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getLogin();
  }
   
  getLogin = () =>{
    let data = { 
      "email": "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
      "password": "123456"
    }

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login",{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .then(data => this.setState({ user : data }));    
  }
   
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              {this.state.user.map(data => (
                <h3> {data.data.access_token} </h3>
              ))}
          </div>
      )
  }
}
```

{

I add the answer returned from the API here.

```
  success: true, access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVmY…I5M30.9r9iRA0lyXTy-MjUr2QN9RrxGneqyUoVZM8eFeXoK1s", data: {…}}
    access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVmYzNmYmFiNjFhOWQzMGQwNDNjY2I0OSIsIm5hbWUiOiJOZW1yYW4gQWtzYWthbCIsImlhdCI6MTYwOTc5MDI5M30.9r9iRA0lyXTy-MjUr2QN9RrxGneqyUoVZM8eFeXoK1s"
    data: {name: "Red Reddington", email: "example@gmail.com"}
    success: true
    __proto__: Object
```

Comment: I think this is because of `.then(response => console.log(response))` when chaining `then` what ever is returned by the previous `then` is what is available in the next `then` as `console.log` does not return anything the next `then` would be receiving `undefined` for its `data` param and you would be setting your `user` state to `undefined`.

Comment: your data is an object with details from an user, not an array of users. also, since this a login user request I suggest you not to use an initial `[]` state, but a `null` state and not use map over `user` since you are not fetching users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not making sure you are iterating over an array. All is happening because chaining then in the promise. what a `then` returns is converted into the input for the next `then`. So the `console.log` one is not returning anything hence the following next is getting `undefined`. Once you solved that issue by removing the log or returning again the response, you need to make sure to save the parts from you need from response into the state.

```
state = { user: [], access_token: '' }

fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login",{
      method:'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((response) => { console.log(response); return response; })
.then((response) => this.setState({ 
    user : response.data,
    access_token: response.access_token 
}));
```

Note: make sure you store access_token to make it reactive into your template.

Answer (score 1):

Got to function getLogIn and remove this line  .then(response => console.log(response))

Comment: Or do `.then(resp => { console.log(resp); return resp; }`

Comment: I removed  `.then(response => console.log(response))` this line but now i'm getting different error like this:  **TypeError: this.state.user.map is not a function**

Comment: It seems like you are calling map on an Object which is not an Array, please make sure that this.state.user is an Array.

Comment: I checked. user state is an array defined by "[]". What else could it be caused by?

Answer (score 0):

delete the code provided in your file

```
  .then(response => console.log(response))
```

Comment: thanks :) i think it must be worked but i'm still getting different error like this: **TypeError: this.state.user.map is not a function**